# insert SET STATISTICS TIME into a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms

Let's say I have the following statement:

```
SET STATISTICS TIME ON;
Select * from myTable
SET STATISTICS TIME OFF;
```

Which produces the following results in the messages tab in ssms:

```
SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 1 ms.
```

How Can I read Elapsed time value into a table/temp table/ table variable?

The reason I want to do that is because I'm testing a query in a loop with different parameters. In order to easier read the elapsed time results I want to insert them into a table and then compare multiple tables for multiple versions of scripts.

Comment: Why not just use [SQL Sentry Plan Explorer](http://sqlsentry.net/plan-explorer/) to execute the different variations of your query? Aside from its initial design (to provide much more meaningful execution plans), it also presents all kinds of runtime metrics for each statement, including I/O and duration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could read the elapsed time by calculating it yourself:

```
declare @StartTime datetime = getdate();
Select * from myTable;
declare @Dur datetime = getdate() - @StartTime;
```

You can then dow what you want with `@Dur`.

For more detailed timings, I would follow Aaron's advice.

Comment: What If I run 100 queries and I need results for each query to be inserted into a table.